# How can I plot this step function using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I plot the following function on matplotlib:

For all intervals t in `[n,n+1]`, `f(t)=1` for n even and `f(t)=-1` for n odd. So this is basically a step function with `f(t)=1` from 0 to 1, `f(t)=-1` from 1 to 2, `f(t)=1` from 2 to 3, `f(t)=-1` from 3 to 4, and so on.

This is my code so far:

```
t = arange(0,12)

def f(t):
    if t%2 == 0:
        for t in range(t,t+1):
            f = 1
        if t%2 != 0:
            for t in range(t,t+1):
                f = -1
```

This is the process of this code:

1. Define t to be in the range 0 to 12.
2. Define the function `f(t)`.
3. Use the statement, if t is an even integer, so it will consider `t=0,2,4,6,8,10,12`.
4. Use the for loop to allow us to define `f=1` for each of these integers.
5. Repeat for odd values of t.

Can you see anything fundamentally wrong with this code? Am I complicating things?

When I try to plot using

```
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(t,f,'b-')
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

I get a `ValueError` saying "x and y must have same first dimension".

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Your code is particularly hard to read. And I'm not sure the indentation is correct. Could you try to fix it?

Comment: So you are trying to plot:
`t    = [0, 1,  1,  2, 2, 3,...]
f(t) = [1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1,...]`
currently your t is equal to `[0,1,2,3,...,12]`. You need to have matching x,y pairs which you don't currently have.

Comment: `matplotlib.pyplot.plot(t,f(t),'b-')` but your function return error. Try `print f(t)` to see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to double up elements in your array `t`, and build the (-1,1) pattern with `1 - 2 * (t%2)`:

```
t = np.arange(13)
f = np.repeat(1 - 2 * (t%2), 2)[:-1]
t = np.repeat(t, 2)[1:]

In [6]: t
Out[6]: 
array([ 0,  1,  1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  4,  4,  5,  5,  6,  6,  7,  7,  8,  8,
        9,  9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12])

In [7]: f
Out[7]: 
array([ 1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1,
        1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1, -1, 1])
```

Perhaps even easier is:

```
In  [8]: n = 12
In  [9]: t = np.repeat(np.arange(n+1), 2)[1:-1]
In [10]: f = np.array([1,1,-1,-1]*(n//2))
```